# I'd like to send a reminder using Google's Apps Script, that pulls different data depending on the actual month of the year

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a calendar that is set up in Google Sheets with information that is displayed in a table like such;

July    Week    System  Activity    Notes   Status
Jul-4   Week 1

Each table is a named range for each month. I have reminder that will be emailed to me but I want the data to changed depending on the month, without me having to go in and manually changing the range listed in the script. Here is my script.

```
function sendMayChecklist() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MM/dd/yyyy")
  var subject = "Daily Update for " + date;
  var recipiants = "byron.lynch@greendot.org";
  var data = sheet.getRange('May').getValues();

  var email_body = '<html><body> Hey Byro <br> <br> Please see your daily checklist below: <br> <br> <table style = border-collapse:collapse; border = 1 cellpadding = 5><tr>';
  for (var row=0;row<data.length;++row){
    for (var col = 0; col<data[0].length;++col)
    {
      if (row==0)
      {email_body+='<th>'+data[row][col]+'</th>'}
      else{
        email_body+='<td>'+data[row][col]+'</td>'
      }
    }
    email_body+='</tr><tr>'
  }
  email_body += '</tr></table><br><br> Thank You </body></html>'
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipiants,subject,"",{htmlBody:email_body})   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM")).getValues();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to change the way the date is formatted when I get the email? Currently it comes up as Sun May 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time). Can I make edits to make that look shorter and cleaner?

Comment: Sure the formatDate() simply returns a string.  It can be anything you wish

Comment: Specifically, the way the date looks in the body of the email, not the subject.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is